# Function that mimics the game of inverting words

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

I need to write a function `lastfirst(lst)` that mimics the game of inverting words: basically if given a list of words, it returns the one that has the first letter different from the last word's letter, else it returns none. For example if i have a list composed of `list = ['car,'rap','fun']` it should return the string`'fun'` or else `None`. I wrote this code:

```
 def lastfirst(lst):
...:     new = []
...:     for x in lst:
...:      string = x[0]
...:      new.append(string)
...:      string1 =x[-1]
...:      new.append(string1)
...:     return new
...:
```

That returns me the first and last letter of every word, but I don't know how to proceed from here. Also ideally it should start from the last letter of the first element and ignore the last letter of the last element.

Comment: Effectively you are just wanting to compare `current_word[0] != previous_word[-1]` and then return it, otherwise return `None` if the loop terminates. Figuring this out how to create a loop along your list should be trivial.

Comment: Also, you should change the variable name `string`, `string1`, and maybe even `lst` to something more descriptive.

Comment: @Bilkokuya i've tried that by writing `if x[-1] != x[0] new.append(x)` but it doesn't work, i guess the prompt reads two x in the same line as the same iteration. Could you give me some more hints?

Comment: `if x[-1] != x[0]` compares the last and first character of the same word. This is not, what Bilkokuya suggested.

Comment: Exactly. How can i separate the values?